# Stored proc behaving differently on two nodes

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-connection, connection-pooling

I have two oracle nodes running on RAC.  Using TOAD I compiled a stored proc.  My Java Application runs on Jboss and use connection pool to the oracle server.  In one node I still see the old query running while the other node behave fine.  How is this possible?  Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: That seems highly unlikely.  I suppose you could be using edition-based redefinition and some connections are set to use a different edition than others.  But it's pretty unlikely that you've done that inadvertently or that you would be using that feature without mentioning it.  More likely, something in your stack outside the database is caching some results or you are misinterpreting something.  What is the procedure doing and why do you believe that you see the old code running on one node.  Are you looking at execution stats in the AWR?

Comment: Yes the DBA looked at the AWR and shared with me.  Initial query used UPPER(column_name) = UPPER(some_string).  Obviously this did not utilize any indexes and cost was pretty high.  The new query resolved that.  This query is part of a package.  When I log on the DB and looked at the package it showed me the new query.  But AWR reported the old query on the 2nd node.  I recompiled the package again using TOAD.  The AWR came clean after that.

Comment: My guess would be that the old query was executed at some point during the AWR window, then the procedure was recompiled, but you still saw an execution of the query during the window.  A RAC cluster only has one instance of an object (per edition) so there is no way that one node could see a procedure definition that the other doesn't (barring a serious bug).